# Public key encryption without ciphertext expansion

Tags: encryption, public-key

Say I have a database column that is defined as VARCHAR(255) that stores names.

I can assume that names can be up to 255 chars.

I need a public key encryption so that I can replace names with their ciphertexts. However the DB structure cannot be changed. In other words I need a public key encryption method that ensures ciphertexts are the same range as plaintexts. (i.e., a permutation).

RSA permutation is no good as it expands ciphertexts to the key size.

surely something like this must exist in the literature. ("format preserving public key encryption" or something like that).

Comment: Why do you require public key encryption?

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9140/991 $\;$

Comment: if that is is ranged 0-255, that is 256 bytes, which is 2048 bits, a standard secure RSA key size

Comment: @DrLecter Several reasons I would need it. The app is running on cloud and stores the data on cloud. The app only writes the data but does not need to read it. Then I would like to use public key encryption to protect it from the cloud provider.

Comment: By a counting argument, strictly non-expanding public-key encryption is bound to be deterministic, hence vulnerable to verification of a successful guess of the plaintext. So at least, it is not applicable to encryption of small or otherwise guessable fields, such as gender, or first name. For the rest, follow Ricky Demer's link.

Comment: It is strictly for use in a deterministic sense. By specifying VARCHAR(255), I assume that it is a deterministic permutation between 0 .. 2^(8*255).